# Laravel 5 Facebook insights: How to get pageImpressions?

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using jonasva's laravel facebook insights package ( https://github.com/jonasva/laravel-facebook-insights).
And stuck at the very beginning. So if someone is familiar and can help me out.

I have setup the facebook-insights.php with all the information that is needed. (AppID, Secret, ermanent access token ...)

However, when I try to get the PageTotalImpressions I receive the number 0

FacebookInsightsController:

```
 //Get Facebook PageImpressions
public function getPageImpressions() {
  $startDate = new \DateTime('2017-01-01');
  $endDate = new \DateTime('2017-03-26');
  // fetch your page's total impressions for a given period
  $totalImpressions = FacebookInsights::getPageTotalImpressions($startDate, $endDate);


  return $totalImpressions;

}
```

I know that there are Impressions, as Facebook Insights shows different numbers.

Any idea what's wrong here ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using this package myself, I stopped and removed it before even delving in.

On the composer install it states that it loaded php-sdk-v4 which has been abandoned jonasva's laravel facebook insights package has not been updated for over 2 years.

I recommend you do the same as me and begin searching for a new package.